# C# create file with same name as folder name, with extension

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a folder called `test`.
Now I pass that folder into a program and it will output a file called `test.xyz` in the same directory that contains the target folder.

The general logic I'm using is something like

```
string outDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
string outName = Path.GetFileName(path).TrimEnd("\\".ToCharArray()) + ".xyz";
string outFile = Path.Combine(outDir, outName);
```

Which works, but it seems kind of excessive to perform so many operations just to build my new filename.

1: Can I reduce the number of Path calls to achieve my result?
2: Can I do something about the second line to avoid trimming and also avoid using that add operation?

Comment: Please let us know whether an answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a FileInfo for that!

```
string path = @"C:\Windows\System32\";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
string outFile = fi.DirectoryName + ".xyz";
```

works like a charm. even with trailing slash in the directory string

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work in my quick tests:

```
string outFile = Path.GetFullPath(path) + ".xyz";
```

Although I just realized your `path` may include a trailing slash already. If you can't change it to avoid that, you'll still have to include the `.TrimEnd()` call.

In my test, I'm using `var path = @"C:\Windows\System32";`.

Comment: in addition to this, you can use Path.Combine to avoid trimming

Comment: @sblom, use @"C:\windows\system32" as test path seemed not safe. lol